# Deploying japplet client Server application to external server

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, japplet

If I have client server application written in java, the client is jApplet and the server is server class the use Socket to listen to any coming request, and also used thread.

The communication between client and server is object serializable classes. Japplet uses localhost and port 8080 to connect to the server.

Now if I want to deploy this client server application to external server, where I have to add the server class, is it under Public_html folder, or under www? the external server has tomcat use 8080 and it is installed under /var/lib, and also has port 80 for regular HTTP request.

And where to add jApplet client class so it can be accessible by the user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[client]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[client-server]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server could be anywhere the important is what port is listening and for the client is the same. 
if you need pass across a router you need verify the redirections ports are succefull.